# Joomla login module in custom file

Tags: php, joomla

We have Joomla all setup and running, however the login module is not where we want it.  The theme we are using had a built in "style panel", something that slides in and out on the right hand side of the page.  We used this to display some user data, however it is not actually a defined position in the gantry framework.

Therefore, we are unable to assign the login module to this area... Does anyone know how to maybe call the elements from the module so they will display where we want it too and have the same functionality?

EDIT: http://demo.rockettheme.com/?template=voxel

The panel on the left side. We have editied that (php file) to display some info we want, however we'd also like the login box there.

Comment: how was the original data being assigned to the style panel?

Comment: Literally just hard coded in, its a php file thats being included.  The file has a few divs inside of each other, with its own styling, then everything else in there is just static code.

Comment: in which case, could you not include all the necessary file for the login module?

Comment: Problem is I don't know which to files to include, nothing happens at the moment so I assume there is a conflict going on somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iclude the files from the login module folder, therefore the following:

```
include (JURI::root() . "modules/mod_login/mod_login.php");

include (JURI::root() . "modules/mod_login/helper.php");

include (JURI::root() . "modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php");
```

Once you have done this, let me know if it works and if not, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: <?php
      
       include('home/lethal/public_html/www2/modules/mod_login/mod_login.php');
       include('home/lethal/public_html/www2/modules/mod_login/helper.php');
       include('home/lethal/public_html/www2/modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php');
      
      ?>

Comment: I have updated my answer. sorry, forgot to use the correct code. hope it works now

Comment: hmm nope, just breaks the page (stops executing)... Thanks for the help anyhow, if you've got any more suggestions give me a shout :)